# "Proving" that $\pi=4$ with Hausdorff measure

Tags: measure-theory, fake-proofs

There is a famous "proof" that $\pi=4$, which goes as follows: Start with a square with side-lengths $1$ and inscribe within it a circle with radius $1/2$.
Next, iteratively "fold" the corners of the square in on itself, maintaining the perimeter of $4$, but "approaching" the circle closer and closer (see e.g. [this image](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-077tVMIvmlo/T8WXPvWEM-I/AAAAAAAAEmM/GvtoToIOW4g/s1600/pi-4.png)).
Repeat ad infinitum and we see that the circumference of the inscribed circle, $\pi$, must be $4$.

Clearly, the proof is wrong.
Usually the explanation is that the approaching of the circle is not smooth enough, and so the circumference doesn't follow along.

However, I think the "proof" can be made rigorous using the Hausdorff measure.
Indeed, let $(A_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be the sequence of approximating shapes, so $A_1$ is the square with side length $1$, $A_2$ has the corners folded in once, etc.
Let also $C$ denote the circle inscribed within them and $\mu$ the $1$-dimensional Hausdorff measure.
Then clearly, $C$ and $A_n$ are measurable for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ since these are Borel sets, and since $\mu$ formalizes the circumference of sets in $\mathbb{R}^2$, we have $\mu(C)=\pi$ and $\mu(A_n)=4$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.
Finally, $\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_n=C$ and $A_1\supseteq A_2\supseteq A_3\supseteq\ldots$, so by continuity of measures, we have
$$
\pi
=\mu(C)
=\mu\Big(\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_n\Big)
=\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(A_n)
=4.
$$

Clearly, something is wrong, but I don't know which of the above steps is erroneous.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Edit: I realized that while it is true that $\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_n=C$ and $A_1\supseteq A_2\supseteq A_3\supseteq\ldots$, the same is obviously *not* true of the boundaries of these sets, and since the Hausdorff measure denotes circumferences only on the boundaries of sets, this is where the mistake lies.

Comment: $\lim (f(x)) \neq f(\lim(x))$

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12906/the-staircase-paradox-or-why-pi-ne4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple things wrong with the proof. If $\mu$ is the $1$-dimensional Hausdorff measure and $A_n$ are the solid regions in the plane inside the folded squares, then $\mu(A_n) = \infty$ for every $n$, and $\mu(C) = \infty$ so while it's true that $\mu(\bigcap A_n) = \mu(C)$, it isn't informative.

If $\mu$ is the $1$-dimensional Hausdorff meausre, and the $A_n$ are the boundaries of the solid regions, and $C$ is the boundary of the disk, then it is no longer true that $A_1\supset A_2\supset\dots$ and it certainly isn't true that $\bigcap A_n = C$, so the result $\pi = 4$ of the final calculation using continuity of measures isn't deduced properly.

Comment: Thanks! I realized this after posting (see edit), but I'll mark your answer as accepted in case someone happens on this post as well